# AMPSCRIPT to Retrieve an Salesforce Object

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Learning how to use AMP to relate an Opportunity D.E. to our Contacts D.E. in order to pull in a Contacts first name for personalization. I am not throwing any errors in my preview and test page, however I am also getting no result. Can anyone help me understand where I made my mistake?

```
%%[ 
  SET @Id =[Primary_Contact__c]
 @ContactRow=RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact','FirstName','Id','=',@Id) 
  SET @FirstName = [FirstName]
  ]%%
```

Comment: `RetrieveSalesforceObjects` returns a row set. You will have to parse it with the `Row` and `Field` ampscript function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you're missing the [`Row`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/row.htm) and [`Field`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/field.htm) function after retrieve function. The retrieve function will give you a rowset and you will need to extract the particular field from that row.

Example:

```
%%[
SET @Id = [Primary_Contact__c]
SET @LookUpCRM = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'FirstName', 'Id', '=', @Id)
IF RowCount(@LookUpCRM) > 0 then
    SET @CRMRow = Row(@LookUpCRM,1) 
    SET @FirstName = Field(@CRMRow, 'FirstName')
ELSE
    SET @FirstName = 'No Name Found'
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: no worries @MarkFreestone